# How do I run SQL scripts from cygwin bash on windows and get the directories correct?

Tags: sql, bash, oracle, cygwin

I've been working on a script that runs various sql scripts based on tested conditions. Each time, I run into problems with the best way to represent the directory of the sql script so bash/oracle can find it. Bash seems to behave differently if you use a variable with the sql script directory and name than if you were typing the directory and name on the command line. For example, this works:

sqlplus x/y@z @//filedir/filename.sql

but this does not

fname="//filedir/filename.sql"

sqlplus x/y@z @$fname

Any ideas?

Comment: I have narrowed it down to cygwin/bash/windows putting control M on the end of every line, including the one listing the filename:ls: cannot access '//filedir/filename.sql'$'\r'. Any simple way to change that behavior?

Comment: You should convert all bash scripts to unix line endings using `dos2unix FILE` or `d2u FILE`. Also make sure your favorite editor can write unix line endings for new files and will preserve the line endings in old files.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I did work around it for most of my stuff with that very solution, but some of these files are only being created with vi from cygwin. Do you know how that might be putting the windows cr/lf on? It's possible somebody else at my work opened them with notepad, but I doubt that since I'm the only one working on them.

Comment: Are you specifying a text mount by any chance?  Normally files created under Cygwin have POSIX line endings.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a text mount. You might be going over my head a bit. :)

Comment: Mounts are binary by default, but can be specified as text mounts, meaning that files will be created with cr/lf endings.  Check if you have a /etc/fstab file, and if you do, see if there are any entries that specify "text" rather than "binary".  See https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table for reference.

Comment: Even though it's windows, I do have an /etc/fstab and it's set to binary for /cygdrive. I think it's just that people are opening files with notepad by default. I'm the one that's pushing for cygwin to be the standard so bash scripts become the standard instead of bat or powershell. Thanks everybody. I'm in business with the dos2unix utility.